# User Session in Rest

Tags: java, rest, session

i'm working a webapp with REST services in java using Spring and AngularJs.

When user authenticates some session data is mantained in the server session (userid, user structure code).

When i do some user request (a product search for example) i need these data (i.e. user structure code).

I can proceed in 2 ways:

1. send the structure code from client
2. get the structure code in server, accessing the user session

In case 1 my REST API should have the structure code in its parameters, but i need to develop some safety check on server, otherwise, theoretically, a 'smart' user can ask for data for other structure codes.

In case 2 my REST API doesn't need the structure code in its parameters, as it can be taken from the session. And i don't need to implement a safety check procedure either, so server can process the requests in a quicker way.

I know REST calls should be stateless, but as i understood, the 'stateless' mean not maintaining session state (i.e. subsequent states changes following requests). In my case i don't maintain session state, but some static user informations.

Is this correct in terms of REST paradigm or i need to pass the structure code in the request, make the safety check procedure etc ?

EDIT
To Clarify, here is an example session object

```
public class userData {
    private String userId;
    private String structureCode;

    ...getters and setters
}
```

Comment: So what happens if you have to expand to multiple servers?

Comment: In any case, I suspect this is the wrong question.  Questions like "Is this correct in terms of the REST paradigm" are sort of useless, because it's not like there are Paradigm Police out there making sure your code meets their standards of purity.  The questions should be something like: what are the advantages of following the REST paradigm; do you need those advantages; if you need those advantages but REST also has disadvantages (like security issues), what's the best compromise that will get you most of the advantage of REST?

Comment: @ajb. Question 1. if i expand to multiple servers a session is created in each server the user connect to. The sessions are identical as they are static data related to the user. Question 2. I'm just trying to understand which is the most correct way to proceed. Of course the right question is the one linked to the best compromise. But anyway what i focus on is the concept of state. Is the session the way i use it a way of maintaning state? I believe not and in a way i just need to reduce the number of queries. So what is best, more queries or little memory drawback? And what is correct?

Comment: I don't understand your example. What is this "user structure code"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: it's just a field. An alphanumeric code that identifies a structure related to the user. Imagine a code which identifies a shop in a network of shops

Comment: i've updated the question with an example data